# Vertical and Horizontal Approach is OSI and TCP/IP model

Tags: tcp, osi

While reading about the OSI and TCP/IP model for communication i came across the terms like OSI model follows vertical approach while TCP/IP model followed a horizontal approach.Can somebody explain what does vertical and horizontal approach here mean.

Comment: Your question is meaningless, or founded on a false premiss. Both models are vertically layered.